# What is exectuted when ajax url is '/'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I feel silly asking this question, but I'm stumped.

I've been a programmer for years, but I'm fairly new to jQuery and ajax.

I have to update an existing WordPress site where the data is in the MySQL database in a table called site_map_equipment.  The table has 5 columns:  eid, mapkey, name, description, and protocol.

The ajax call to display the information is:

```
function getMapEquipmentData(mapkey) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/',
    data: "map_equipment=" + mapkey,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('.mapkey-content').html('<p><img src="' + imgurl + '/loading.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Loading..." /></p>');
    },
    success: function(request) {
      $('.mapkey-content').html('<img src="' + imgurl + '/map-key-icon-' + mapkey + '.png" width="27" height="24" alt="" /><h5>' + request.name + '</h5><p>' + request.description + '</p>');
    },
    error: function(request, err) {
      $('.mapkey-content').html('<p>A problem occured while accessing the data.</p>');
    }
  });
}
```

Another ajax call specifies a url of '/wrhsac/' which I would think would be a subdirectory, but no such subdirectory exists.

I have always directed an ajax call to the PHP file, but what is executing the request when the url is '/' or '/wrhsac/'?

Comment: Depends on how the server is configured.

Comment: A server can be configured to respond with anything, for any URL. It totally depends on the server-side software.

Comment: In the typical php application setup, `/` would target the `index.php` in the root folder of your website root. However, that behavior can be modified by .htaccess, or by whatever you are using to serve files (apache, nginx, iis, node.js, etc)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no definitive answer.

Comment: Hints on where to look would be nice.  I had already thought of the index.php  file in the root folder, but there is no logic there.  and nothing in the .htaccess file either (thanks KevinB).

Comment: What no one is mentioning, and what might actually be the thing you're confused about, is that `/` goes to the root URL of the domain you're currently on. So if your page is at `http://my.domain.com/my-web-page.php`, `/` will direct the client to `http://my.domain.com/`. A `<base>` tag might affect this, on the off chance you're using one.

Comment: Depends on server code. In Java  servlet/ Filter You may set some default response for all client calls.. Every call would pass this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the hints!

I based on the hints I was getting, it made me look in a few places I hadn't thought of.

Low and behold in the WordPress functions.php file:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

if( $map_equipment != null ) {
    $result = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT * FROM `site_map_equipment` WHERE `mapkey`=' . $map_equipment, ARRAY_A);
    print json_encode($result);
    exit();
}
```